# Inserting into an Sqlite database with LINQ in Mono throws TargetInvocationException and SqliteException

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, linq-to-sql, mono

I'm trying to open a Sqlite file and insert a row into a table with Mono. I've referenced the `Mono.Data.Sqlite`, `System.Data`, and `System.Data.Linq` assemblies. Both the Sqlite file and the table exist. The `Status` class has `Table` and `Column` attributes. When I use Mono's Sqlite library alone, I can successfully insert.

```
Status data = GetStatusFoo();
using (SqliteConnection con = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=" + Config.SQLITE_DB_FILE + ";Version=3;"))
{
    con.Open();

    using (SqliteCommand cmd = new SqliteCommand("INSERT INTO " + _table + _insert + " VALUES " + _values, con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@Timestamp", data.Timestamp));
        // ...
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    con.Close()
}
```

However, I don't want to type out 1000 SqliteParameters, so I'm trying to use Linq-to-SQL. The following code throws a TargetInvocationException in the `DataContext` constructor.

```
Status data = GetStatusFoo();
using (DataContext db = new DataContext("Data Source=" + Config.SQLITE_DB_FILE + ";Version=3;"))
{
    Table<Status> statuses = db.GetTable<Status>();
    statuses.InsertOnSubmit(data);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

It complains that `Version` isn't a valid keyword, so when I remove it, leaving just

```
Status data = GetStatusFoo();
using (DataContext db = new DataContext("Data Source=" + Config.SQLITE_DB_FILE + ";")
{
    Table<Status> statuses = db.GetTable<Status>();
    statuses.InsertOnSubmit(data);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

it throws a System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException at `db.SubmitChanges()` that the "Server does not exist or connection refused".

However, this changes when I use a SqliteConnection for DataContext's IDbConnection, i.e.

```
Status data = GetStatusFoo();
using (SqliteConnection con = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=" + Config.SQLITE_DB_FILE + ";"))
using (DataContext db = new DataContext(con))
{
    Table<Status> statuses = db.GetTable<Status>();
    statuses.InsertOnSubmit(data);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

This throws a Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: `SQLite error   unrecognized token: "@"` at `db.SubmitChanges();`.

Adding the `Version=3;` back doesn't help, and trying `Version=2` throws a System.NotSupportedException. The Console and DataContext.Log give something like this:

```
INSERT INTO [Status] ([Timestamp], ...) VALUES (@Timestamp, ...)
-- @Timestamp: Input Int64 (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [1397710927]
-- ...
-- Context: SqlServer Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.0.0.0
SELECT @@IDENTITY
-- @Timestamp: Input Int64 (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [1397710927]
-- Context: SqlServer Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.0.0.0

Unhandled Exception:
Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: SQLite error
unrecognized token: "@"
```

What gives? Why doesn't it like the "@" symbol? Is it failing to do Parameter substitution? Or is it the `@@IDENTITY` call at the end?

EDIT: Additional Info

After poking around the stack trace, the SqliteException exception occurs in Mono.Data.SqliteCommand.BuildNextCommand, and `this.CommandText` == `"SELECT @@IDENTITY"`. Apparently this MS/Transact-SQL command isn't supported by SQLite. From what I can tell, an "outputCommand" for this is created in `DbLinq.Data.Linq.Sugar.Implementation.QueryRunner.Upsert (target={Status}, insertQuery={DbLinq.Data.Linq.Sugar.UpsertQuery})`

So I'm altering my question to include: how do I tell Linq to avoid SQL-only commands?

Answer (score 1):

I have a partial answer to my question.

Adding `DbLinqProvider=sqlite;` to the SqliteConnection query string tells Linq-to-SQL to use SQLite commands, and fixes the `"SELECT @@IDENTITY"` issue. This code works:

```
Status data = GetStatusFoo();
using (SqliteConnection con = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=" + Config.SQLITE_DB_FILE + ";DbLinqProvider=sqlite;"))
using (DataContext db = new DataContext(con))
{
    Table<Status> statuses = db.GetTable<Status>();
    statuses.InsertOnSubmit(data);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

However, I still have to use a `SqliteConnection` object, because `new DataContext("Data Source=" + Config.SQLITE_DB_FILE + ";DbLinqProvider=sqlite;")` still throws the "Server does not exist or connection refused" exception.

Edit: Complete answer

It turns out that without a `DbLinqConnectionType` parameter, the DataContext defaults to using `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` for its connection. The connection type has to be an assembly fully qualified name, so the following code works for me:

```
// in Config
public static string SQLITE_CONNECTION_CLASS_AQN = typeof(Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection).AssemblyQualifiedName


// in database class
static string _connection_string = "Data Source=" + Config.SQLITE_DB_FILE + ";DbLinqProvider=sqlite;DbLinqConnectionType=" + Config.SQLITE_CONNECTION_CLASS_AQN + ";";


// in database method
Status data = GetStatusFoo();
using (DataContext db = new DataContext(_connection_string))
{
    Table<Status> statuses = db.GetTable<Status>();
    statuses.InsertOnSubmit(data);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

For reference, `typeof(Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection).AssemblyQualifiedName` evaluates to `"Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection, Mono.Data.Sqlite, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756"`.